# J2ME Hashtable comparison

Tags: java-me, hashtable

I'm dealing with a little bit issue when I try to compare two hashtables in J2ME.

This is the situation:

Fist, I've two hashtables:

- parkingSlot(String SlotId, String Vehicle)
- vehicles(vehicleID,"Available");

is it possible to find this?

parkingSlot
01  "Available"
02  XSD123
03  ASD423
04  "Available"
05  "Available"

vehicules
XSD123  "Available"
LAE212  "Available" 
EDO987  "Available" 
ADE934  "Available"
ASD423  "Available"

I need to get the car plates that exist in both hashtables. I tried using two iteration with Enumeration adding the values from the first hashtable and the keys from the second one to another hashtable or making a comparison between each one and I can't

Can someone give me a hand with this? ( I can attach my test code )

Answer (score 1):

Finally I get the solution for this case: I add the content of the first Hashtable to a Vector and the I compared the Vector and the second hashtable deleting the data duplicated